# Recommend a good javascript statistics library?

Tags: javascript, statistics

Can anyone recommend a good javascript statistics library?

Perhaps one recommendation per question, and let the votes push the best to the top.

note: 
Searching for javascript statistics seems lead one towards attempts at gathering statistics, I'm more interested in actual statistical calculations such as standard deviation and the like.

Comment: Personally I like FusionCharts [http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/].  Easy to manipulate with PHP/AJAX.

Comment: Here is one I came across - http://macwright.org/simple-statistics/

Comment: If you are interested in statistical distributions, see [stdlib](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/88c1a0ca14e19162600ecf0ec6530f2b3902f0e0/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/math/base/dist).

Comment: https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics
https://github.com/jstat/jstat

Answer (score 8):

jStat is a statistics library written in Javascript. http://www.jstat.org/

Comment: I didn't find a way to automatically display a bars chart of mean with standard errors. Am I missing something?

Comment: I like this library. However, I would skip the download on the jstat home page (I couldn't get it to work) and go straight to the github repo: https://github.com/jstat/jstat (use "src/core.js")

Comment: This library has no API documentation!

Comment: @sanity Unfortunately there is no API documentation on the website, but there is some useful docs within the GitHub repo https://github.com/jstat/jstat/tree/master/doc/md

Comment: jstat looks good, but why isn't there a harmonic mean function? Arithmetic mean, geometric mean and median are available.

Answer (score 5):

Found this one on google:

http://pseudosavant.com/blog/2010/12/22/javascript-statistics-and-math-library/

It seems that it adds some methods to the Array object to get std. dev., variance, median, and a few more, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: A new version of the library just came out. It has more functionality like sampling, histograms, percentile, etc, http://pseudosavant.com/blog/2013/06/14/psmathstats-2-0/. It is also available on GitHub now too: https://github.com/pseudosavant/psMathStats

Comment: @DaveRomero - The link you posted is not active anymore.

Comment: @Mutant- thanks, that's embarrassing. Should've hosted on github pages.  Back up now. Let me know what you think and if there are functions you're looking for that aren't included yet.  Cheers

Comment: At second glance, looks like there was a typo in the link.  Here's the correct one:
[javascriptstats.com](http://www.javascriptstats.com) (I am the author)

Comment: To prevent future search fails:
The - currently - working link to the PS code is https://github.com/pseudosavant/psMathStats, disregard other links in these answers they are deprecated or 404. Hope it helps