# Is there any statistical library for javascript?

Tags: java, math, statistics, javascript

I need to implement some statistical tests like: T-test, Anova and Wilcoxon on javascript.

Similar to Java's - Apache Commons Math Library, is there any statistical tests library or codes for javascript?

Comment: +1 math is rad! I'm interested as well

Comment: JavaScript is not really a good tool for statistical analysis. It's either not fast enough or does not give a good high level API like R.

Comment: @Raynos the demos are responsive ;-) http://www.jstat.org/demonstration

Comment: @daniellmb JavaScript can do it, But it's not the best tool for the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommend a good javascript statistics library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742393/recommend-a-good-javascript-statistics-library)

Comment: JavaScript is perfectly capable of statistical analysis. As a language, JavaScript is plenty fast enough and high level APIs can be written which are comparable to libraries written in R and Python. For a library which implements some of the statistical tests mentioned in the OP, see [stdlib](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib), a library which includes well-tested and robust implementations for numeric computation.

Answer (score 12):

`jStat` : a JavaScript statistical library

https://github.com/jstat/jstat

Comment: I couldn't find API documentation nor "wilcoxon" or "anova" keyword in the source code..

Comment: You never accepted any answer. You can accept  answer that really helped you. Go through FAQ document at stackoverflow if you don't know how to upvote and accept a answer

Answer (score 4):

[OpenEpi](http://www.openepi.com) is a Javascript stats library, is open source, and has ANOVA and t-tests. I've not tried it (it's a bit too focused on epidemiology for my needs) but it might be useful.

---

[**jStat**](http://www.jstat.org) is a javascript statistical library project, and it looks like it's got a great future, but it might not have all you need right now. **Edit:** as of Dec 2012 it looks like the jStat project *page* is no longer maintained but the *project* is continuing to be developed. There's [more up to date documentation on github](http://jstat.github.com/all.html). It now does have [anova tests](http://jstat.github.com/all.html#anovaftest) and [varieties](http://jstat.github.com/all.html#t_Statistics) of [t-test](http://jstat.github.com/all.html#ttest). No sign of Wilcoxon signed-rank though.

---

If you need very specific statistical processing in javascript urgently, you might have most success by browsing [Omegahat](http://www.omegahat.org/) who have various little tools that bridge the established stats language **R** with others including javascript.

It'll depend on the details of exactly what you want to do, but you *might* have some success with packages such as [RJavascript](http://www.omegahat.org/RJavaScript/) - a code translator which aims to help turn existing R features into Javascript (just don't expect quality results first time). Also, [SpiderMonkey](http://www.omegahat.org/SpiderMonkey/) builds on R for browsers, so it might be useful for internal or personal uses (but it's unlikely to be suitable for public publishing).

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I ported https://code.google.com/p/statistics-distributions-js/ so that I could use it in http://elem.com/~btilly/effective-ab-testing/ - it may have the functionality you need if you only need simple things.

Comment: It looks easy to implement tprob but I couldn't find anova or wilcoxon tests in this library

Comment: @orhun-alp-oral: For ANOVA you need the student's t distribution, which is there.  The wilcoxon is indeed missing, however for n > 20 it is reasonable to use the normal distribution instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple library for descriptive statistics, you could use [javascriptstats.com](http://javascriptstats.com)

It does:

- Mean
- Median
- Mode
- Range
- Variance
- Standard Deviation

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging a related answer:

The following blog post lists some recent packages: http://jgoodall.me/posts/2012/02/01/javascript-statistical-libraries/

As mentioned by others, native JS is a far cry from R, which web-wise has progressed from RApache (http://rapache.net/) to shiny (http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/). The latter uses node.js server-side, so this is quite promising. Of course both approaches will require you to code stats in R server-side, instead of using JS either on client or server.

Marc