# Javascript Statistics Library with Certain Tests

Tags: javascript, statistics

I have several data "layers" over the same list of "samples". Some layers are continuous float data, some are multinomial/categorical data, and some are binomial/dichotomous/boolean data. In my Javascript web application, I want users to be able to select a set of samples and see which layers are significantly different between the selected set of samples and all other samples. The end result should be a p-value for each layer, from a two-tailed test (where applicable) of the null hypothesis that the distribution over selected samples is the same as the distribution over unselected samples.

I've done the mathematical reasoning and determined that I want to use a [Mann-Whitney U test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann-whitney_u_test) for the continuous data, a [Pearson's Chi-Squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) for categorical data, and a [Binomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) (exact, without the normal approximation) for dichotomous data. All of these tests are available in the excellent [scipy.stats library](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) for Python.

Is there a Javascript library available with implementations of these tests? Failing that, is there a Javascript library that provides PDFs and PMFs and CDFs of the distributions that would be required to implement these tests, like the Chi-squared distribution, or the (discrete) binomial distribution? Failing that, is there a resource available that explains how these tests work with an eye towards implementation? Failing that, is there a library of basic mathematical functions for probability, like erf or the gamma integral?

I am aware of [jStat](http://www.jstat.org/), which seems to provide only a few continuous distributions with no API documentation, and of [OpenEpi](http://www.openepi.com), which is more of a monolithically integrated epidemiological statistics system than a usable library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer, just evidence to the negative.

Apart from never encountering such a powerful library I have googled a little and found no results other than jStat. However I have found a page (http://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/stat-data/Javastat.htm) where some client-side statistical calculations can be performed. This is not a library, and I have had a look at some of their javascript and it seems like they have coded the calculations by hand (which I wouldn't expect if a library existed)

So at best I offer some evidence to the negative.

(Also note the rather inconclusive post [Recommend a good javascript statistics library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742393/recommend-a-good-javascript-statistics-library))

I wouldn't want to do heavy numerical integration in javascript though, can't you do that on the server-side instead, especially if the user is merely selecting data, and not entering it?